# Does the Fighter Dedication require Strength AND Dexterity, or Strength OR Dexterity?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, multi-classing, archetype

In general, Fighters are free to choose between these stats when building for the class. They must invest in one, but rarely need both.

However, as written, the [Fighter dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=7) appears to require investment in both. It makes a fighter archetype singularly unappealing for, for example, a heavy armor wearing Champion.

Is that accurate?

Comment: And even when the Champion _can_ take it, there is hardly any benefit

Comment: Sure. It was just the first example that came to mind of a heavy armor using character.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Fighter Dedication requires Strength AND Dexterity

The prerequisites for [Fighter Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=709) are:

> **Prerequisites** Strength 14; Dexterity 14

Feats that have prerequisites that are satisfied by an OR specify it. For example, [Magus Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2945) requires [Strength OR Dexterity] AND Intelligence:

> **Prerequisites** Strength 14, or Dexterity 14; Intelligence 14